# How to add previous button to jQuery record

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code below which work fine with **next button**. Now I want to add **previous button** to be able to view previous record. This is what I did:

```
if(i > 0) {
  $('#prev_btn').html("<a data-role='button' href='#' id='next_btn'>Previous</a>");
}
```

How can I implement the **previous button**? Here is my coding effort

```js
var json = [{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe"
}, {
  "firstName": "Anna",
  "lastName": "Smith"
}, {
  "firstName": "Peter",
  "lastName": "Jones"
}];

i = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#next_btn').on('click', function() {
    $('#data').empty();
    if (i < json.length) {
      var firstname = json[i].firstName;
      var lastname = json[i].lastName;
      $('#data').append('<p>' + i + '- First Name: ' + firstname + ' - Last Name: ' + lastname + '</p>');
      i++;
      if (i > 0) {
        $('#prev_btn').html("<a data-role='button' href='#' id='next_btn'>Previous</a>");
      }
    } else {
      $('#data').append('<p><b>No more record!</b></p>');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>My record</h1>
<div id="data"></div>
<a data-role="button" href="#" id="next_btn">Next</a>
<div id="prev_btn"></div>
```

Comment: Please see my updated answer. It has a version that does show the message AND disables when showing the message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check this out?

```js
var json = [{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe"
}, {
  "firstName": "Anna",
  "lastName": "Smith"
}, {
  "firstName": "Peter",
  "lastName": "Jones"
}];

i = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#next_btn').on('click', function() {
    $('#data').empty();
    if (i < json.length) {
      var firstname = json[i].firstName;
      var lastname = json[i].lastName;
      $('#data').append('<p>' + i + '- First Name: ' + firstname + ' - Last Name: ' + lastname + '</p>');
      i++;
      if (i > 0) {
        $('#prev_btn').html("<a data-role='button' href='#' id='prv_btn'>Previous</a>");
        $('#prv_btn').on('click', function() {
          if(i>0) {
            $('#data').empty();
            var firstname = json[i-1].firstName;
            var lastname = json[i-1].lastName;
            $('#data').append('<p>' + (i-1) + '- First Name: ' + firstname + ' - Last Name: ' + lastname + '</p>');
            i--;
          }
          else {
            $('#data').empty();
            $('#data').append('<p><b>Already first record!</b></p>');
          }
        })
      }

    } else {
      $('#data').append('<p><b>No more record!</b></p>');
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>My record</h1>
<div id="data"></div>
<a data-role="button" href="#" id="next_btn">Next</a>
<div id="prev_btn"></div>
<script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to click twice on previous to see "No more records"

Answer (score 1):

You can bind click event to multiple elements with using `,` like `$('#next_btn, #prev_btn')`.

Inside `function` you can get `id` of `clicked` `element` with `$(this).attr('id')` and based on `next` or `prev` button click use `i++` or `i--`.

Based on my opinion you can `show/hide` `previous`, `next` buttons. Rather than changing `html`.

Rest of code is self explanatory. If still have any confusion then left the comment.

Try it below.

```js
var json = [{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe"
}, {
  "firstName": "Anna",
  "lastName": "Smith"
}, {
  "firstName": "Peter",
  "lastName": "Jones"
}];

let i = -1;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#next_btn, #prev_btn').on('click', function() {
    $('#data').empty();
    $(this).attr('id') == 'next_btn' ? i++ : i--;

    if (i >= json.length) {
      $('#data').append('<p><b>No more record!</b></p>');
      $('#next_btn').hide();
    } else if (i < 0) {
      $('#data').append('<p><b>First record!</b></p>');
      $('#prev_btn').hide();
    } else {
      var firstname = json[i].firstName;
      var lastname = json[i].lastName;
      $('#data').append('<p>' + i + '- First Name: ' + firstname + ' - Last Name: ' + lastname + '</p>');
      $('#prev_btn, #next_btn').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>My record</h1>
<div id="data"></div>
<a data-role="button" href="#" id="next_btn">Next</a>
<div id="prev_btn" style="display:none;"><a data-role='button' href='#'>Previous</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. DRY: Don't repeat yourself
2. Toggle disabled of the bottons when reaching first or last record then no need to show a message

```js
const json = [{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe"
}, {
  "firstName": "Anna",
  "lastName": "Smith"
}, {
  "firstName": "Peter",
  "lastName": "Jones"
}];

let idx = -1;

$(function() {
  $('.nav').on('click', function() {
    idx += $(this).is("#next_btn") ? 1 : -1
    $('#data').empty();
    if (idx >= 0 && idx < json.length) {
      var firstname = json[idx].firstName;
      var lastname = json[idx].lastName;
      $('#data').append('<p>' + idx + '- First Name: ' + firstname + ' - Last Name: ' + lastname + '</p>');
    } 
    $("#prev_btn").prop("disabled", idx < 1)
    $("#next_btn").prop("disabled", idx >= json.length - 1)

  });
  $("#next_btn").click(); // show first
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>My record</h1>
<div id="data"></div>
<button type="button" data-role="button" class="nav" href="#" id="prev_btn">Previous</button>
<button type="button" data-role="button" class="nav" href="#" id="next_btn">Next</button>
```

If you DO want to show the message:

```js
const json = [{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe"
}, {
  "firstName": "Anna",
  "lastName": "Smith"
}, {
  "firstName": "Peter",
  "lastName": "Jones"
}];

let idx = -1;

$(function() {
  $('.nav').on('click', function() {
    idx += $(this).is("#next_btn") ? 1 : -1
    $('#data').empty();
    if (idx >= 0 && idx < json.length) {
      var firstname = json[idx].firstName;
      var lastname = json[idx].lastName;
      $('#data').append('<p>' + idx + '- First Name: ' + firstname + ' - Last Name: ' + lastname + '</p>');
    } 
    $(this).siblings(".nomore").toggle(idx<0 || idx >= json.length) 
    $("#prev_btn").prop("disabled", idx < 0)
    $("#next_btn").prop("disabled", idx === json.length)
    
    if (idx<0) idx = 0;
    if (idx>=json.length) idx = json.length-1;

  });
  $("#next_btn").click(); // show first
});
```

```css
.nomore { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>My record</h1>
<div id="data"></div>
<button type="button" data-role="button" class="nav" href="#" id="prev_btn">Previous</button>
<button type="button" data-role="button" class="nav" href="#" id="next_btn">Next</button> <span class="nomore">No more records</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

try :

```js
var json = [{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe"
}, {
  "firstName": "Anna",
  "lastName": "Smith"
}, {
  "firstName": "Peter",
  "lastName": "Jones"
}];

i = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click','#next_btn', function() {//   <=========  this line changed
    $('#data').empty();
    if (i < json.length) {
      var firstname = json[i].firstName;
      var lastname = json[i].lastName;
      $('#data').append('<p>' + i + '- First Name: ' + firstname + ' - Last Name: ' + lastname + '</p>');
      i++;
      if (i > 0) {
        $('#prev_btn').html("<a data-role='button' href='#' id='next_btn'>Previous</a>");
      }

    } else {
      $('#data').append('<p><b>No more record!</b></p>');
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>My record</h1>
<div id="data"></div>
<a data-role="button" href="#" id="next_btn">Next</a>
<div id="prev_btn"></div>
```